# Is SVM rotation invariant?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, transformation

Let's say we have some data X and we want to find a linear separator using soft SVM with l2 regularization, and then we want to solve the same problem after applying some rotation matrix Q to the data set. Should we expect anything to change?

The way I think about it, it doesn't make sense for anything to change because rotation matrix preserves norm and the its transpose is also its inverse, so mathematically:

[image]

So the solution should be identical and solving the two problems should yield the same accuracy and the same loss (having the same loss function).

Is something about this reasoning wrong?
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I believe you're correct.  Small nitpick - I'd call it "rotation equivariance" instead of "invariance."  Because it's not that the results doesn't change (invariance), it's that the separating hyperplane is rotated in the same way as the data (equivariance).

Comment: @bogovicj Is it possible to say anything about what would happen with a logistic loss function? (meaning log of sigmoid)
That is a strictly decreasing function so no minimum, I wonder if something can definitively be said about the solution of those problems then. Will the regularization-loss tradeoff make it so the accuracy will change no matter how many gradients steps we take, or we can expect the accuracy of both models to reach a static identical point with enough steps?